# div element couldn't load css file

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, load

I am using primefaces I would like to put all my css in a separate file css.  when I put my style into the same page xhtml,it's work with me, like :

```
<h:body>

    <div style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:#E9F3FF">

    </div>
</h:body>
```

but when I put my css in a separate file it's doesn't work with me ,like

```
    <h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
        <div class="index_center_text">

        </div>
    </h:body>
```

or

```
<h:head>
<h:link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.css" />
<h:body>

            <div class="index_center_text">

            </div>
</h:body>
```

style.css :

.index_center_text{

```
height:200px;
width:100%;
background-color:#E9F3FF
```

}

Folder structure

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |    |    `-- style.css
 |    `-- images
 |         |-- logo.png
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- lib
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    |-- web.xml
 |         
 |-- index.xhtml
```

please anybody can help me !

Comment: @Anonymous you're right , do you have an answer please

Comment: No, I've never used that language. I would only say your path may be wrong, but it seems you've already checked that. Still, posting the same question again is not okay.

Comment: If you want to draw more attention to a question, you can read [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you.

```
<h:head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>
</h:head>
```

Comment: first thanks for your replay. I tried it but still didn't work with me